# SSL connect error (schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_ILLEGAL_MESSAGE

Tags: bash, cygwin

I try to install [spotdl](https://spotdl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installing-ffmpeg) using **cygwin**

```
git clone https://github.com/spotDL/spotify-downloader && cd spotify-downloader
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
pip install poetry
poetry install
python3 scripts/build.py
```

Very hard problem is this command

```
pip install poetry
```

**LOG**

```
Collecting rpds-py>=0.7.1 (from jsonschema<5.0.0,>=4.10.0->poetry)
  Using cached rpds_py-0.9.2.tar.gz (16 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [467 lines of output]
      Collecting maturin<2.0,>=1.0
        Using cached maturin-1.1.0.tar.gz (181 kB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting tomli>=1.1.0 (from maturin<2.0,>=1.0)
        Using cached tomli-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
      Building wheels for collected packages: maturin
        Building wheel for maturin (pyproject.toml): started
        Building wheel for maturin (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        × Building wheel for maturin (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [443 lines of output]
            running bdist_wheel
            running build
            running build_py
            creating build
            creating build/lib.cygwin-3.4.7-x86_64-cpython-39
            creating build/lib.cygwin-3.4.7-x86_64-cpython-39/maturin
            copying maturin/import_hook.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.4.7-x86_64-cpython-39/maturin
            copying maturin/__init__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.4.7-x86_64-cpython-39/maturin
            copying maturin/__main__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.4.7-x86_64-cpython-39/maturin
            running egg_info
            creating maturin.egg-info
            writing maturin.egg-info/PKG-INFO
            writing dependency_links to maturin.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
            writing requirements to maturin.egg-info/requires.txt
            writing top-level names to maturin.egg-info/top_level.txt
            writing manifest file 'maturin.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
            reading manifest file 'maturin.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
            reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
            warning: no files found matching '*.json' under directory 'src/python_interpreter'
            writing manifest file 'maturin.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
            running build_ext
            running build_rust
            cargo build --manifest-path Cargo.toml --message-format=json-render-diagnostics --release -v --no-default-features --locked
             Downloading crates ...
            warning: spurious network error (3 tries remaining): [35] SSL connect error (schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_ILLEGAL_MESSAGE (0x80090326) - This error usually occurs when a fatal SSL/TLS alert is received (e.g. handshake failed). More detail may be available in the Windows System event log.)
            warning: spurious network error (3 tries remaining): [35] SSL connect error (schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_ILLEGAL_MESSAGE (0x80090326) - This error usually occurs when a fatal SSL/TLS alert is received (e.g. handshake failed). More detail may be available in the Windows System event log.)
 Caused by:
              [35] SSL connect error (schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_ILLEGAL_MESSAGE (0x80090326) - This error usually occurs when a fatal SSL/TLS alert is received (e.g. handshake failed). More detail may be available in the Windows System event log.)
            error: `cargo build --manifest-path Cargo.toml --message-format=json-render-diagnostics --release -v --no-default-features --locked` failed with code 101
            [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for maturin
      Failed to build maturin
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for maturin, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I installed cygwin using `mirrors.kernel.org` mirror

Comment: Install wheel “pip install wheel” since that’s the source of your error. You might find it easier to use WSL2 rather than Cygwin